# How to convert jQuery function to on() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a function from the `jquery.event.drop` plugin found at http://threedubmedia.com/code/event/drop/demo/selection:

```
$(selector).drag("start", function( ev, dd ){});
```

How can I convert this to work using the `on()` method?

Something like this (not working):

```
$(document).on("drag", selector, "start", function(ev, dd){});
```

Comment: are you trying to delegate the drag or just convert to the `on` method?

Comment: I need the code to work for appended elements, so I use on() for jquery version 1.10.2.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: ([working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xq6pT/))

```
$(document).on("dragstart",selector,function(ev,dd){ });
```

Comment: This only works using jquery version 1.7.2, but not 1.10.2. Any other suggestions?

Comment: works in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xq6pT/) with version 1.10.2. I'm using Chrome if that makes any change..